# WordPress wp_get_current_user returning blank values until refresh

Tags: theme-development, filters, hooks

I'm developing a site in WordPress and creating my own theme.  As part of the theme, I have a custom user login.  When a user logs in, the form action directs back to itself and in the header of the page, I have a simple script which determines if the user is logged in or not.

While this script runs as expected, the issue I encounter is trying to load the user's first and last name with the use of [wp_get_current_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) function, the name returned is blank on the initial load (although it does show once the page is refreshed or when migrating to a new page).

I've searched several user questions and articles and many of them mention hooking into the init function (such as [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30061/wp-get-current-user-always-returns-0)), but none of them provide additional detail on this.  I've attempted to add a filter to the init function, but have had no luck.

Here's my code to handle the login, located at the start of the header.php file:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $userLoggedIn = true;
    if (isset($_POST['spLogout'])) {
        wp_logout();
        $userLoggedIn = false;
    }
} else {
    $userLoggedIn = false;
    if (isset($_POST['spLogin'])) {
        $ax_user = $_POST['email'];
        $ax_pswd = $_POST['pswd'];
        $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => $ax_user,
            'user_password' => $ax_pswd,
            'remember'      => true
        );

        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false);

        if (is_wp_error($user)) {
            echo $user->get_error_message();
        } else {
            $userLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And in my functions.php file, here is the hook and function:

```
add_filter('init', 'ax_get_user_info');
function avox_get_user_info() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
        $fName = $currentUser->user_firstname;
    }
    return $fName;
}
```

I'd like to be able to load user information without requiring a page refresh. 
 Perhaps I'm doing this wrong, I'm only just starting to learn about hooks and loading order within WordPress, but any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header.php file is going to be called after the **init** action. If you want the logic to run in your header.php file first, maybe you can hook into another action done at a later point in WordPress:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'ax_get_user_info');
function avox_get_user_info() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
        $fName = $currentUser->user_firstname;
    }
    return $fName;
}
```

***init*** is done very early on, while ***wp_head*** is called in your header.php file most likely after your other logic is being fired. You can see here init is called before get_header, which is calling your header.php file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  That being the case, is it possible (or even advisable) to hook into wp_head before init?

Comment: Hooking into one is no different than hooking into the other. It's just a matter of when your function is going to be called on which action.